# How to find number of connected components of graph G?

Tags: functions, graphs-and-networks

Is there a command that can count the number of components of a graph, in the same way that `VertexCount[G]` counts vertices?

Comment: Please give us an example and your desired output :)

Comment: I want the number of connected components. For the graph in the picture here: wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory) I would want the number 3 as output.

Comment: See [ConnectedComponents](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ConnectedComponents.html) in the docs. `Length@ConnectedComponents[g]` gives the number of components in graph `g`.

Comment: Solved, thank you @kguler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Documentation of [`ConnectedComponents`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ConnectedComponents.html)

```
g = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1, 4 <-> 5}, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 5]
```

[image]

```
ConnectedComponents@g
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}}
> ```

So `Length@ConnectedComponents@g` gives you the number of connected components.

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
testg = Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 
   4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 5}]
```

[image]

```
ConnectedGraphQ[testg]
```

yields False

Finding connected components:

```
ConnectedComponents[testg]
```

yields:{{4, 3, 5}, {2, 1}}